# Sgt. Pepper's Album Cover: Paul's Uniform matches the Blue Sky

Tags: album, the-beatles

[image: Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band album cover]

I am noticing now that the tint of the uniform that Paul is wearing on the cover of this album matches that of the sky in the background.  Also, Paul is the central figure on the cover, positionally speaking.  There are two other pop culture characters with this color, one to the left and one to the right.  (as we look at Paul, to his right is a woman (Mae West?) and to the left there is a man.  Each have this color)

I have done a pretty rigorous search on the Internet to see if this has been mentioned.

Has anyone heard theories on this?

Comment: Why would you expect there to be theories about the color choices?

Comment: @PiedPiper There are already a number of theories and lore about this album and Paul especially.

Comment: Can you point to which people you are referring to?  There is an nice interactive version found here https://sgtpepper.udiscovermusic.com/

Answer (score 2):

Your rigorous internet search turned up nothing on this, which leads me to fear there is nothing to be found—perhaps because the colours don't really match. I've shown this here by pulling down pieces of sky to Paul's left and right for a more direct comparison with his uniform:

[image]

Circumstantial evidence strongly suggests there is no connection between the things coloured blue: the fact that the backdrop is only a painting means it would have been very easy to arrange for an exact colour match, if a match had been wanted.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer cannot be considered objective, because you chose to match up two different swatches of blue, where there are gradients.